# Grails app doesn't hotswap changes

Tags: grails

I have several grails 2.0 apps that work just fine.  However, one of them won't hotswap changes in development.  Any ideas what to look for?  I haven't done anything on purpose to config anything related to this.

It fails to hotswap both in Intellij and also run from the command line with grails run-app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using windows?

There is an issue with this, I've had the same problem and I'm afraid others have as well - [this link](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8573) will provide som info.

When I was using Grails 1.3.7 it was working fine, as soon as I upgraded to 2.0.0 (unsure about the version) I had to restart it all the time. My solution was switching to Linux.

Comment: Yes it's awful! If you don't really need 2.0.0 use 1.3.7.